# I can't see Wifi adapters in my Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, wifi, usb

I installed Ubuntu 18 on a Vmware.
I am trying to use a wifi adapter. But I can't use it.
can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**It depends what you want to do:**

1. If you just want to use the host's Wireless Adapter to connect to the network instead of the Wired one (The tyranny of the `Default`) just:

   - <kbd>Edit</kbd> your VM settings
   - Change `VMNet Information` to `Bridged`
   - Change `Automatic` to the actual adapter you want to use

**OR**

2. Run hacking tools from the safety from your VM: *You can't,* because:

   - All Vendors support Windows
   - Some support MacOS
   - Very few support Linux (Yes, I'm looking at you, Broadcom!)
   - None support specific VMWare drivers <sub><sup>(that I know of)</sup></sub>